# Dataset Selection - iloc[] - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a huge dataset and I want to get some of its columns. Is there any way to avoid typing all the numbers?

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('final.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [1,2,3,..,50]].values
```

Comment: No, it's not working. @AK47

Comment: You should edit your question and make it more clear exactly what you're trying to do with some sample input/output

Comment: `X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:50].values` or directly `dataset = pd.read_csv('final.csv',usecols=[x for x in range(1,50)])`